# SMTP sink socket server in PHP

Tags: php, smtp

Recently found [this simple SMTP python](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/96/) script and trying to do the same in PHP.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import datetime
import asyncore
from smtpd import SMTPServer

class EmlServer(SMTPServer):
    no = 0
    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        filename = '%s-%d.eml' % (datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'),
                self.no)
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        f.write(data)
        f.close
        print('%s saved.' % filename)
        self.no += 1


def run():
    # start the smtp server on localhost:1025
    foo = EmlServer(('localhost', 1025), None)
    try:
        asyncore.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I have tried [Navarr's socket class](https://github.com/navarr/Sockets) (a simple php socket server) to receive the data and save it to a file. A set up EchoServer shows when I telnet to it and type. When I set my mail-client to connect to the EchoServer connects but breaks after a timeout. Obviously because it is not getting a reasonable reply ... any idea how I get similar function like the python?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by using [FakeSMTP](https://github.com/axllent/fake-smtp) and made it to work with xinetd instead of inetd by adding this conf:

```
service fakesmtp
{
    socket_type = stream
    protocol    = tcp
    user        = root
    wait        = no
    server      = /pathto/fake-smtp.php
}
```